# iTunes Match and Library on NAS

Tags: itunes-match, nas

I just got a new MacBookAir for my home. It will primarily be used at home with some occasional use out of the house. I would like to use the iTunes server on my Synology NAS to store a downloaded copy of my iTunes libray for use a time. My understanding is that I can do this by pointing iTunes to the iTunes server directory on my NAS. Here's the issue, I believe that when I am out of the house, it will search for that library and not find it. Will iTunes know to automatically revert to iTunes Match streaming if it can't find the library?

Comment: why don't you just use dyn-dns so you have access to your nas from all over the world (as long as you have internet)?

Comment: I have access to the files I need on my NAS when I am not home via the Synology Cloud Station package. I am fine streaming music via iTunes Match if I am not home.

Comment: for me itunes match isn't the option (don't want to pay to get my music in a cheaper quality) - i can't tell u if it will do what you want and also can't test it - but i solvedthe same problem as you have  with using the privat sharing  of itunes on my server (currently just a nas with dyn.dns) - itunes on my mac is set up with a local library and just a few audio files i always need to have (also when there is no internet) every thing else i stream from my nas over private sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not be able to automatically switch. What you'll have to do is create a new iTunes library that is used for streaming only. To do this, open iTunes while holding the Option key. Then selected "Create new library" and name it something different, I used "iTunes Streaming". Then, simply turn on iTunes Match and you'll see all your playlists populate. Once you do this, you'll be able to stream all your music directly from Apple. When you're back home, open iTunes again while holding the Option key and select your original library.