# Stream matched/uploaded music when local files are not available

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I use iTunes a lot on the go but I have my music at home on an external harddisk. Every time I try to play a song in iTunes I receive a message that the original song cannot be found. The laptop I use on the go is the same as the one I used to index my iTunes library. Only after clicking cancel in the dialog box the song is streamed.

Is there any way to directly stream the music? That's kind of the whole idea of Match right?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating another iTunes library and switch between the two libraries: [iTunes Match and Library on NAS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134855/itunes-match-and-library-on-nas).

See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201596